# Carrierwave, creating a duplicate attachment when duplicating its containing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I would like to duplicate a model. The original model contains an attachment through Carrierwave. Ideally, a new attachment would be created, that is a copy of the original image, for the new model object.

I have looked through the Carrierwave documentation, and googled this problem, but have not found a solution that creates a new duplicate of the original image. Is this reasonable? Possible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't believe Carrierwave has this option. However, you can make use of the *_remote_url= method to set the new model's picture to be a duplicate of the first.

Here's a brief example

Say I have a model which has_one :photo attached with carrierwave. I can duplicate, the model, set the photo to the previous one and save it. Example:

```
first_model = User.first
duplicate_model = first_model.dup #(where the dup code duplicates everything else you need)
duplicate_model.remote_photo_url = first_model.photo_url
duplicate_model.save
```

This would then "copy" the photo from the first object into your second as a new carrierwave attachment.

Comment: When attempting to use this code, the first_model.photo_url returns a file path, not a url. I know that this can be converted to a URL, and there is obviously a webserver nearby, since this is a RoR project. It would be nice if processing the file would be more direct, since it is easy to imagine a scenario where a URL is not available for particular images.

Comment: yup :) - you can refer to this question for turning the path into the full URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484809/full-url-for-an-image-path-in-rails-3/15011797#15011797

Answer (score 8):

While `copy_carrierwave_file` is a neat gem it is not nescessary as long as you use local storage.
`carrierwave` can use local files as source of attachments and you can use this to duplicate the attachment:

```
first_user = User.first
duplicate_user = first_user.dup
duplicate_user.photo = File.open(first_user.photo.file.file) if first_user.photo.present?
duplicate_user.save
```

This is more efficient than routing the image twice through your web server.

Comment: It works well but if I have has_many association that contains images too, how it can be handled? Like a user has many books and a single book contains image too. How it will be handled? Thanks.

Comment: You will have to loop over the association (books) and do the duplication of the image in each book as described.

Comment: Yes, that's right I did the same and ended up having another issue. Can you please review my this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248320/how-to-copy-duplicate-has-many-association-and-update-few-columns Thanls Martin.

Answer (score 7):

Try this gem https://github.com/equivalent/copy_carrierwave_file , it handles both local storage and Fog storage

```
original_resource = User.last
new_resource      = User.new

CopyCarrierwaveFile::CopyFileService.new(original_resource, new_resource, :avatar).set_file    

new_resource.save
nev_resource.avatar.url # https://...image.jpg
```

Comment: That is really simple and works really well. Thanks for creating and sharing that.

Answer (score 3):

For me with CarrierWave 0.10 this works just fine:

```
user = User.first
dup_user = user.dup
dup_user.photo = user.photo
dup_user.save
```

Although I'm not sure how this works out when using cloud storage like S3

Comment: Although this works, you run through another round of likely expensive image processing, regardless of the state of the first image.

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from the [Carrierwave wiki page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog):

```
YourModel.find_each do |ym| 
  begin
    ym.process_your_uploader_upload = true # only if you use carrierwave_backgrounder
    ym.your_uploader.cache_stored_file! 
    ym.your_uploader.retrieve_from_cache!(ym.your_uploader.cache_name) 
    ym.your_uploader.recreate_versions!(:version1, :version2) 
    ym.save! 
  rescue => e
    puts  "ERROR: YourModel: #{ym.id} -> #{e.to_s}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to fully duplicate the whole version set on S3, while some of the versions were **cropped**.

Unfortunately, `remote_#{column}_url=` method was of no help, because by the time the versions are recreated, there are no crop params on the `model`:
I used [RailsCasts approach](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast) using `attr_accessor` to crop the avatar, and those params weren't stored in the DB.

After some research and a lot of failures, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57740479/3082929) and noticed that `copy_to` method.
It turned out that both `SanitizedFile` and `Storage::Fog` have it, so it's possible to use it for local and S3 files. I didn't however investigate how it literally works and decided to let Carrierwave a chance to take care of it.

```
class AvatarUploader 
  …

  def duplicate_to(target)
    return unless file.present? && target.logo.file.present?

    versions.keys.each do |version|
      public_send(version).file.copy_to(target.avatar.public_send(version).path)
    end
  end
end
```

That's all it takes to fully duplicate the images, no matter if they are cropped or not.
There's a catch, however: you should only call `duplicate_to` after the model is already saved with other avatar, or the target path would be `nil`. Thus, one useless round of processing takes place for the new record.

```
new_user.assign_attributes(old_user.slice(:avatar, :avatar_alignment))

# Won't work!
old_user.avatar.duplicate_to(new_user) # => as the `new_user` hasn't persisted yet, its avatar files are Tempfiles
new_user.save # => will recreate the versions from the original image, losing the cropped versions!

# But this works
new_user.save # => the avatar will be stored as a set of versions created from the original (useless processing)
old_user.avatar.duplicate_to(new_user) # => the avatar files will be rewritten by the copies of old_user files
```

I think it's a good idea to store the crop params somewhere in the DB in a JSON-like object for such cases (and to be protected from losing cropping data when you have to `recreate_versions!`), but if that's not an option, this solution might be what you seek.

As this thread is the first G-link when searching for *carrierwave duplicate*, I decided to post this answer exactly here.
Carrierwave `1.3.2` with fog-aws `1.2.0`.

Hope this helps someone or the future me!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
user = User.first
dup_user = user.dup
dup_user.photo = user.photo
dup_user.save
```

Reference: https://codeutility.org/ruby-on-rails-carrierwave-creating-a-duplicate-attachment-when-duplicating-its-containing-model-stack-overflow/