# How to copy/duplicate has many association and update few columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deep-copy

I am using **deep_clonable** gem and its working fine but the problem is that when it comes to copy and updating certain columns in has many associations, it just steals the existing one and update them to new records which is big problem.

I need to copy the image from both models (course and chapters) so I am updating columns in the different way in my code.

Code:

```
def duplicate_records
    new_course = self.deep_clone
    new_course.image = File.open(self.image.file.file) if self.image.present?
    new_course.save
    new_course.chapters = self.chapters
    new_course.chapters.each do |chapter|
      new_chapter = chapter.clone
      new_chapter.image = File.open(chapter.image.file.file) if chapter.image.present?
      new_chapter.save
    end
    new_course
  end
```

Also any best practices to cope with such issues of copying etc?

I mean how good/bad it is to use deep_clonable for this job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is exactly what deep_clonable is designed for.

Concerning copying uploades files, there is a chapter in the documentation, that explains this case:
https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable#cloning-models-with-files